# Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app) while trying google sign in

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I tried changing versions, reading docs and many more but still this error comes. trying to use signInWithGoogle.
firebaseInit.js

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/analytics";

const config = {
  //config
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

export const myFirebase = firebase;
export const myProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const myAuth = firebase.auth();
export const myFirestore = firebase.firestore();
export const myAnalytics = firebase.analytics();
```

Login.js

```
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { myAuth, myProvider } from "../../firebaseInit";

function Login() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(myAuth);

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    myAuth.signInWithPopup(myProvider).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
return (
    <>
      <div className="login">
        <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign In With Google</button>
        {user ? 'welcome' : 'bye bye'}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

versions I am using right now are  -
"firebase": "^7.20.0",
"react-firebase-hooks": "^2.2.0",

Comment: You are probably initializing firebase twice in your application, check all calls to firebase.initializeApp(config) in your code...

Comment: used if (!firebase.apps.length)  still not working